# Use USB scanner on home network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-shares, home-networking, scanner

I've seen similar questions asked before, but they're kind of old. So I'm opening a new question to see if anything new has happened in this area.

I have an Epson ES-400 and I'd like to put it on my home network. Yes, I'm aware there's a wireless version, but I got this as a gift (from someone who probably thinks wireless mice come from the pet store); didn't have the receipt, and I didn't even realize it wasn't wireless until I set it up months later. So I'm stuck with this thing.

With that said, I'd love to get it up and running somehow on my network. I've seen solutions where people share the scanner from a Windows host PC. While I guess the easiest solution, it's not ideal; I don't want to have to leave a PC on all the time just for the scanner. I was thinking maybe getting a single board computer like a Raspberry Pi for this (but as far as I can tell, the ES-400 isn't supported by SANE). I could run ReactOS on an x86 single-board computer, but those are considerably more expensive. I also have an old router acting as an access point running DD-WRT (but I'd assume that's be the same as using the Pi since it'd rely on SANE).

Are there any other good ways I could get this on  the network? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any "small" hardware like a RaspPi or an old router with an USB port will do, as long as you can install software on it. These small computers will typically use Linux.

To make it accessible to the rest of your network, use something like [Sane over network](https://wiki.debian.org/SaneOverNetwork#Sharing_a_USB_Connected_Scanner). I don't know if that will work with Windows clients.